# Banking applications in php

Tags: java, php, c++

> There is an unacknowledged war that goes on every day in the world of
>   programming. It is a war between the humans and the computer
>   scientists. It is a war between those who want simple, sloppy,
>   flexible, human ways to write code and those who want clean, crisp,
>   clear, correct ways to write code. It is the war between PHP and
>   C++/Java.
>   - Adam Bosworth, from a 2004 speech on the primacy of simple, sloppy
>   systems over rigid, perfect ones.

I came across the above quote recently.
Somehow I think if it's a war, then to win it there has to be a popular Banking application built in PHP which is also in use. Why Banking, I don't know :-) But I would like to know if there are any Banking applications built with PHP and also in use by real banks?

Answer (score 5):

Probably... the answer is "no".

Is there any facebook game developed in C++?

;)